# NSLocalizedString random problem

Tags: objective-c, nslocalizedstring

i've a strange problem with following code:

```
NSString *string = NSLocalizedString("hello",nil);
```

actived by tapping a button. If i use a simple string all ok, if i use the localized string after 1-2 tap on the button the app crash without any error, i really don't understand why, can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually passing @"hello"? what you have here is not an NSString.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to miss: you should use **@**"hello", not a "hello". NSString* constant must be defined with preceding @.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
NSString *string = NSLocalizedString(@"hello",@"");
```